# How to fix these ui.bootstrap warnings in AngularJS?

Tags: angularjs, angular-bootstrap

I am using `ui.bootstrap` in `AngularJS`. But it throws warnings about deprecated `services`. How can I resolve these warnings?

[image]

Comment: if you are using `ui.bootstrap`, you need `uib-` attributes

Comment: @AlekseySolovey You saying like this(uib-tooltip="Hello")

Comment: All the solutions are written in the warnings itself..

Answer (score 1):

If you updated `ui-bootstrap` version number, make sure to check breaking changes.

One of those is, as you identified, the service name change from `$modalInstance` to `$uibModalInstance`.

Change all instances in your code base e.g.

`app.controller('AppCtrl', ['$modalInstance', function ($modalInstance) {}])`

To

`app.controller('AppCtrl', ['$uibModalInstance', function ($uibModalInstance) {}])`

And for the future, make sure you [read the changelog](https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md) and check for breaking changes before updating library versions.

Comment: Hi, 
I am using this version (ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.14.3.min.js).

Comment: Well, the docs for that version clearly show what the services are called now. http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/versioned-docs/0.14.3/#/modal

Comment: Hye I am not using $tooltip but I am getting this warning
($tooltip is now deprecated. Use $uibTooltip instead.)

Comment: Surely you are using `$tooltip` somewhere in your app. Do a global search to find all occurrences

Comment: If this helped you resolve your issue, please accept it as the answer